# Unwanted space in AppBar while switching tabs

Tags: flutter

I have an AppBar which looks like this on the initial load of the app:

[image]

If I navigate to another screen by tapping an item in the BottomNavigationBar, the title in the AppBar gets displaced:

[image]

Here's the code for my custom AppBar:

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatefulWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  String playerBalance;

  CustomAppBar(double balance) {
    playerBalance =
        FlutterMoneyFormatter(amount: balance).output.withoutFractionDigits;
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);

  @override
  _CustomAppBarState createState() => _CustomAppBarState();
}

class _CustomAppBarState extends State<CustomAppBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      primary: true,
      actions: <Widget>[
        Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
            child: Row(children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.account_balance_wallet,
                color: Color(0xFF6078ea),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              Text(
                "\$${widget.playerBalance}",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              )
            ]))
      ],
      title: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(
                text: 'MY',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Muli',
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: Color(0xFF6078ea))),
            TextSpan(
                text: ' APP',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Muli', color: Colors.red, fontSize: 18)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Using the Flutter inspect tool, it looks like this additional RichText widget is getting added somehow. I can't figure out where this is coming from.

Comment: remove back button from appbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [`leading`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/leading.html) to `null` and [`automaticallyImplyLeading`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/automaticallyImplyLeading.html) to `false`.